# Typeahead:How can I segregate list of data into 3 different parts ? [Like Multidataset]

Tags: javascript, typeahead.js, typeahead, bootstrap-typeahead, twitter-typeahead

I am working on typeahead.js where user can search by name or speciality or any other keyword.Now I want to populate the data with three different fields.I have three fields 
1.people, 
2.specality 
3.park. 
The information user types should be shown in these three different segments
as shown in MULTIDATASET

```js
var nbaTeams = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('team'),
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  prefetch: '../data/nba.json'
});

var nhlTeams = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('team'),
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  prefetch: '../data/nhl.json'
});

$('#multiple-datasets .typeahead').typeahead({
  highlight: true
},
{
  name: 'nba-teams',
  display: 'team',
  source: nbaTeams,
  templates: {
    header: '<h3 class="league-name">NBA Teams</h3>'
  }
},
{
  name: 'nhl-teams',
  display: 'team',
  source: nhlTeams,
  templates: {
    header: '<h3 class="league-name">NHL Teams</h3>'
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="multiple-datasets">
  <input class="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="NBA and NHL teams">
</div>
```

Coming to my scenario the data is showing in single data set only..
 The remote url data will be coming from the server which is not just an simple array it is object of object of objects.Currently  I am able to populate data with single remote url. But I am not able to achieve multidataset.
[JSFIDDLE:](https://jsfiddle.net/tata93/qg929hvo/)`enter here`
Note: As the url is from the server side.I dont want to disclose information regarding that.In my local it works fine.Below is the image how I am getting results.
[image]
Any help would be greatly appreciated.Thanks.
[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/tata93/qg929hvo/1/)`CHECK HERE`

Answer (score 0):

Substitute `remote` at `.typeahead` for [`Bloodhound`](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/bloodhound.md) to make request; [`templates`](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/#custom-templates), `suggestion` options at `.typeahead` to set result rendered at `html`. See also [Create customize Type-Head using jQuery and Bootstrap-Typeahead?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28253261/create-customize-type-head-using-jquery-and-bootstrap-typeahead/) , [Bootstrap Typeahead not showing suggestion which have the valueKey starting with same value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30258673/bootstrap-typeahead-not-showing-suggestion-which-have-the-valuekey-starting-with/)

```
    templates: {
        suggestion: function(data) { // data return from `Bloodhound`
             console.log(data);
             return "<ul><li>" + data.result[0] + "<li>"
                    + "<li>" + data.result[1] + "<li>"
                    + "<li>" + data.result[2] + "<li></ul>"
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, First of all thanks for the answer, It was bit confusing for me to understand this. As I have said the data is coming from server in the form of object of objects.
Is there any possibility for you to make a fiddle for clearer understanding?

Comment: `@tata See https://jsfiddle.net/9gbp5jd5/ . Try typing "devloper" or "project". Note, you can also use `substringMatcher` function to without using  `.typeahead` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33739881/how-to-send-data-in-request-body-when-using-typeahead-bloodhound/33765633#33765633

Comment: Thanks for the help,I am getting somewhat nearer to my solution, my question is can we list set-1 names under one category and set-2 names in one category with heading mentioned above them like 
Example :- All parks  come under one category i.e set-1 
All foods under category 2 i.e set-2
Is there any javascript can we write?
Note : This all should happen in drop down like shown here http://code.runnable.com/V-41juBwuSBhFaPv/output